# Literal suffix for small integers

Tags: c#

When I have small numbers to be used with long integers I rarely add the special suffix automatically.
For example I would write:

```
for (uint div = 0; div < 100; div += 2)
{
}
```

instead of

```
for (uint div = 0U; div < 100U; div += 2U)
{
}
```

Just out of curiousity, does the compiler treat both examples differently? And if so, does it optimize? Integers are primitive types, so there won't be any casting right?

Comment: The generated IL code is the same.

Comment: This is a widening conversion, meaning that it cannot possibly cause data loss, and therefore the compiler can handle it automatically. The two code samples are identical. And even if there *were* casting, there would be no cost, as these are literals. All the casting would be done at compile time.

Comment: @CodyGray, you should make your comment an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two code samples are identical.

This is a widening conversion, meaning that it cannot possibly cause data loss, and therefore the compiler can handle it automatically. All widening conversions are implicit conversions. You can read more about data type conversions in the .NET Framework [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98bbex99.aspx).

The following would also be a widening conversion, and therefore done implicitly:

```
int  value = 16;
long other = value;  // the int is implicitly converted to a long
```

All of these widening conversions are possible, and done implicitly:

```
 byte          => short, short, int, uint, ulong, float, double, decimal
 sbyte         => short, int, long, float, double, decimal
 short         => int, long, float, double, decimal
 ushort        => int, uint, long, ulong, float, double, decimal
 int           => long, float, double, decimal
 uint          => long, ulong, float, double, decimal
 long          => float, double, decimal
 ulong         => float, double, decimal
 float         => double
```

You mention casting in the question. Casting is *explicit* conversion (as opposed to implicit conversion). In this case, there is no casting, as the conversion is implicit. But even if there were casting, there would be no cost in this case, since these are numeric literals. All of the casting would be done at compile time. This code would be functionally equivalent, too:

```
for (uint div = (uint)0; div < (uint)100; div += (uint)2)
{
}
```

but not something you should write, since the pointless casting adds unnecessary clutter that obscures the meaning of the code.